# Capybara: Click or select option from <select> results into click outside the drop-down list

Tags: selenium, capybara

I explain my problem with capybara and selenium:

I have got a select with various options. I click on select to open the drop down list and then I click on the specific option or I select it, through the following code:

```
puts "Select contract for order?"
all("select#contract_id")[0].click
within all("select#contract_id")[0] do
  @order_name = all("option")[4].text
  @order_name = @order_name.split[0]
  all("option")[4].click
end
all("select#contract_id")[0].click
  within all("select#contract_id")[0] do
  all("option")[4].select_option
end
```

I even tried with:

```
select "@order_name", from "contract_id"
```

Some times it works but some other times it seems like if I clicked somewhere outside the drop-down list with the result that no option was selected.

Does anyone know a most reliable technique?

Luca

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have understood that

```
within all("select#contract_id")[0] do
  @order_name = all("option")[4].text
  all("option")[4].click
end
select @order_name, from: "contract_id"
@order_name = @order_name.split[0]
```

creates some problem for some unexplainable reason. But

```
within all("select#contract_id")[0] do
  @order_name = all("option")[4].text
end
select @order_name, from: "contract_id"
@order_name = @order_name.split[0]
```

works fine